# What is contiguous premise culling and dangerous contact culling?

Tags: pathology, epidemiology

I am reading this [paper](https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masfz/Pop_Dyn/PAPERS/KeelingFMD2001.pdf) related to FMD (foot and mouth disease) epidemics which occurred in UK. It mentioned about terms like IP (infected premise culling), CP (contiguous premise) and DC (dangerous contact cull). IP is the mandatory slaughter of all livestock on an infected premise. But what is CP and DC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Dangerous Contacts were defined as premises where animals have been in direct contact with infected animals or have, in any way, become exposed to infection
>
> Contigous Premises are defined as a category of dangerous contacts where animals may have been exposed to infection on neighbouring infected premises

Tildesley, Michael J., et al. "The role of pre-emptive culling in the control of foot-and-mouth disease." Proceedings of the Royal Society B: Biological Sciences (2009): rspb20090427.

Comment: Oh great. This helped me a lot.